# How to get data from multiple tables and turn them with each in erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails

### Want to achieve

ruby 2.6.5
rails 6.0.3

Thank you for your interest.
I am creating a web application with rails.

I would like to know how to extract only the data of the columns I want from multiple tables, put them into an array, and then output them using each.

### Details

I want to extract the relevant users.name, companies.company_name, and tasks.task_name from the following table and put them into an array as a single unit.
I want to output the array we have created in this way, one at a time, using each in erb.

**Like this**

```
・john Acompany task3
・white Dcompany task12
・carl Bcompany task8
・mark Ccompany task97
```

##### tables

users table

| id | name | sex | company_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | john | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | white | 1 | 4 |
| 3 | carl | 1 | 2 |
| 4 | mark | 1 | 3 |

companies table

| id | company_name | industry_1 | industry_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Acompany | 3 | 9 |
| 2 | Bcompany | 6 | 10 |
| 3 | Ccompany | 1 | 3 |
| 4 | Dcompany | 4 | 8 |

tasks table

| id | task_name | company_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | task3 | 1 |
| 2 | task12 | 4 |
| 3 | task97 | 3 |
| 4 | task8 | 2 |

### Tried

I thought that I could pack each element into an array as shown below. But I couldn't imagine how to implement it, so I gave up.

```
user_name = []
users.each do |user|
  user_name << user.name
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`joins`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/joins) method from ActiveRecord and get the columns you're looking for with `pluck`:

```rb
user_details = User.joins(company: :tasks).pluck("users.name", "companies.company_name", "tasks.task_name")
#=> [["john", "Acompany", "task3"], ["white", "Dcompany", "task12"], ...]
```

Next, iterate over the array of arrays that was returned from the above code to display the data in the way you want. Keep in mind in that in your DB architecture a company `has_many` tasks so you may end up with several arrays for the same company if that company has more than one task.

```rb
user_details.each do |user_detail|
  puts "・ " + user_detail.join(" ")
end
```

Other (and preferred) solution based on comment from [max](https://stackoverflow.com/users/544825/max) :

```rb
User.includes(company: :tasks).each do |user|
 # Here you can retrieve and display the data you need using user.name, user.company.name, user.company.tasks
end
```

Comment: It should be noted that while pluck is a good tool for certain performance critical applications using arrays of arrays of strings is generally not a good way to build MVC apps as you're completely skipping the M and making the view do all the work of making sense of all the data. You instead want to use eager loading and possibly decorators or delegation.

Comment: That's a very good comment. So would you rather suggest something like `User.includes(company: :tasks)` and iterating over that in the view? I don't quite understand your point regarding "making the view do all the work of making sense of all the data" though, would you mind elaborating?

Comment: Yes I would. By making the view do the work I mean that you're writing `user[0]` instead of `user.name` and if you have to deal with any columns that are not just simple strings like dates or from this example the sex your view will have to make sense of the raw data from the database.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a good idea. By passing arrays from your controller to the view you're skipping the model layer completely and skipping all it provides in terms of desearialization and encapsulation (and more). Dealing with simple arrays also destroys the readability of the code:

```
# which one of these was what now?
<tr>
  <td><%= data[0] %></td>
  <td><%= data[1] %></td>
</tr>
```

It is after all a MVC framework built in an object oriented language. Your code should not look like that.

Instead you can either use eager loading and delegation:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :company
  delegate :name, to: :company, prefix: true
end
```

```
@users = User.eager_load(:company)
             .all
```

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Company</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <%= @users.each do |user| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= user.name %></td>
      <td><%= user.company_name %></td>
      # ...
     </tr>
  </tbody>
<% end %>
```

In some cases you may want to use `joins` instead to just select a single column or an aggregate from the assocation through:

```
class UsersController
  def index
    @users = User.joins(:company)
                 .select(
                   'users.*', 'companies.name AS company_name'
                  )
  end
end
```

When it comes to tasks you have to figure out what it is that you want to actually display. Since the assocations is most likely many to many to both users and companies its not clear which task should even be listed. All of them? The first? The last?